# links to sample projects to practice .NET and Oracle technologies

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, oracle, oracle11g

I am planning to practice and learn .NET C#, WCF, ASP.NET web services and Oracle 11g (SQL/PL Sql).

What I am thinking is to work on developing a sample project involving above technologies, so that I can learn technologies at the same type practice them efficiently.

I need guidance to links where I can get some business scenarios or requirements where I can use all the above technologies and implement a sample project.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is download [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). It is free and it will allow you to setup a "playground" for you to work with. The next thing I'd do is download [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) and install it on your virtual machine. Finally, I would download [Oracle 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) which is also free. Install that on your virtual machine too.

Now you have a virtual environment where you can do whatever you want and practice Oracle and .NET to your heart's content without messing up your current system. Once all is setup, you can learn more about Oracle and .NET from the [Oracle .NET Developer Center](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)